# Order of an integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Why is it true that:

> if a has order 3 modulo p then $1+a+a^2 \equiv 0 \, \text{mod}\, p$

Thank you!

Comment: Are we working under multiplication or addition as our operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$(1+a+a^2)(a-1) \equiv a^3-1\equiv 0$$